# How to properly use distinct_id in mixpanel

Tags: analytics, mixpanel

I am trying to create a mixpanel funnel using PHP backed which includes following events

1. Home Page Viewed
2. Signup
3. Dashboard Viewed
4. Submitted Code

Currently I am doing this w/o using distinct_id and thus mixpanel trends are pretty accurate but funnel which depend upon unique user count gives false data.

How should I use distinct_id property to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9):

I'm not a PHP developer, but I'm working with Mixpanel at the moment and just encountered a similar problem. You have two options- either [force a unique identifier on the frontend](https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/javascript-full-api#identify) that you can also determine easily on the backend (such as a user's ID), or use the default Mixpanel-provided identifier when you make calls from the backend. The first option can cause some consistency pitfalls, particularly if you're trying to create a funnel involving something like user signup. The second option, however, is fairly foolproof:

Mixpanel sets a cookie named "mp_YOUR-PROJECT-TOKEN-HERE_mixpanel" for each user. That cookie contains, among other things, the distinct_id that Mixpanel is using for that user on events triggered from the frontend. If you extract that value from the cookie and explicitly pass it as the distinct_id param to your Mixpanel calls on the backend, you should get consistent flows and working funnels.

Note that, for ease of use, Mixpanel also allows you to set cookie_name as an argument to set_config or init in the frontend javascript:

```
mixpanel.init("PROJECT-TOKEN-HERE", {cookie_name: foo})
```

Though for some reason that gives you a cookie named "mp_foo" instead of just "foo". At any rate, best of luck.

Comment: hi @Andrew , i think instead of parsing cookie ... you can just use mixpanel.get_distinct_id()

Comment: @webhobbit it's been quite some time since I've worked with Mixpanel- I know that method exists in the javascript, but have they added it to a backend library of some kind? I skimmed over their PHP API just now and didn't see it.

Comment: yes, your are right, it exist only in javascript. can you read mixanel cookies in backend ? are there created in your domain ?

Comment: @webhobbit yup! That's how I got this working from a Rails backend. Same principles should work fine in PHP.